# When making the camera follow a ball, which one should control the camera position? The ball or the camera itself?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity3D and now creating a trivial (useless) game as follows.

[image]

The ball rolls down the inclined floor and the camera must follows the ball with the following relationship

- `x` camera = `x` ball
- `y` camera = `y` ball + 3
- `z` camera = `z` - 10

There are two possible ways to control the camera position.

## The ball controls the camera

In this scenario, I attach the following script to the ball.

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform cameraTransform;

    void Start() { }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newCameraPos = new Vector3
        {
            x = transform.position.x,
            y = transform.position.y + 3f,
            z = transform.position.z - 10f
        };
        cameraTransform.position = newCameraPos;
    }
}
```

## The camera controls itself

In this scenario, I attach the following script to the camera.

```
public class Camera : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform ballTransform;

    void Start() { }


    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 newCameraPos = new Vector3
        {
            x = ballTransform.position.x,
            y = ballTransform.position.y + 3f,
            z = ballTransform.position.z - 10f
        };
        this.transform.position = newCameraPos;
    }
}
```

## Question

Even though both methods work as expected, I am wondering whether there are any pros and cons for each method. Which one should I use?

Comment: I would put the logic in the camera. At some point you may want the camera to follow something other than a ball.  Maybe a cut-scene, or a level opening fly-though, where it follows a trail of arbitrary points.  It will be a lot easier to abstract that away if the camera handles it rather than each individual object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, both examples work as expected.

What I like to do though, is assign functionality to the object that is responsible for performing the 'action'. In this case the camera is 'following' something. At the moment, it is following the ball, but later if you wanted to make it follow something else, would it make sense to have to navigate to your ball gameobject to change that behaviour? I think not.

By assigning functionality to objects based on 'responsibilities' you will often find that your code ends up being much more modular in the long run.

Of course this sort of practice is nothing new to game development, or software development at all. It complements the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and shares many of its qualities.

But, at the end of the day, if you're working on your code alone, then you will know the codebase inside out. So it's up to you really!

I would also suggest creating `Components` based off of those responsibilities whenever possible. So instead of having one generic `Camera` component, I would create a `FollowTarget` component and attach that to the camera. In doing so, you will have enabled the ability to use that very same `Component` to make some other, arbitrary object follow another arbitrary object in your game.

Happy learning!

Comment: I want to add that the implementation/handling, as you said, should (almost) always be at the altered/performing entity, but sometimes things can be a bit more convoluted/complex. Depending on the situation sometimes reversing the dependency/control direction makes sense. I'm not expert but in those situations I find delegates/events quite useful.

Comment: I love to enforce single responsibility via events, though I am not sure I would consider that an inversion of dependency in this particular case. 

For example, if I have a combat component that fires an event when its attached entity gets 'hit', I might have an animation component listen to that event and play a 'hurt' animation when it's fired.

With this kind of approach, functionality is still assigned "to the object that is responsible for performing the action" as I mentioned in my answer; The combat component deals with combat and the animation component with animating.